# AWS SDK Java Tagging Run Instances

Tags: java, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

Our AWS team enabled tags in INSTANCE and VOLUME and now we have to modify our codes to add tagging. I tried to tag an EC2 instance but I got the following error below and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

The Issue:
The error is saying the instance or the volume is missing mandatory tags.

This is my sample code, if tagging is turned off this code will work.

```
try {
String accessKey = "XXXXXX";
String secretKey = "XXXXXX";
AwsBasicCredentials credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey);

Ec2Client ec2 = Ec2Client.builder().region(Region.of("ca-central-1")).credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build();

IamInstanceProfileSpecification iamSpec = IamInstanceProfileSpecification.builder().name("PROFILE1").build();

List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();

tags.add(Tag.builder().key("Department").value("IT").build());
tags.add(Tag.builder().key("Team").value("DEV").build());

TagSpecification tagSpecs = TagSpecification.builder()
.resourceType(ResourceType.VOLUME)
.resourceType(ResourceType.INSTANCE)
.tags(tags)
.build();

RunInstancesRequest runRequest = RunInstancesRequest.builder()
.imageId("ami-xxxxx")
.instanceType(InstanceType.C5_2_XLARGE)
.keyName("xxx")
.subnetId("subnet-xxxxx")
.iamInstanceProfile(iamSpec)
.securityGroupIds("sg-xxxxxxx")
.tagSpecifications(tagSpecs)
.maxCount(1).minCount(1).build();

RunInstancesResponse response = ec2.runInstances(runRequest);

if (response.sdkHttpResponse().isSuccessful()) {
System.out.println("Successful");
} else {
System.out.println("Not Successful");
}
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolved the issue by separating the volume and instance

```
TagSpecification tagVolume = TagSpecification.builder().resourceType(ResourceType.VOLUME).tags(tags).build();

TagSpecification tagInstance = TagSpecification.builder().resourceType(ResourceType.INSTANCE).tags(tags).build();

RunInstancesRequest runRequest = RunInstancesRequest.builder()
.imageId("ami-xxxxx")
.instanceType(InstanceType.C5_2_XLARGE)
.keyName("xxx")
.subnetId("subnet-xxxxx")
.iamInstanceProfile(iamSpec)
.securityGroupIds("sg-xxxxxxx")
.tagSpecifications(tagVolume, tagInstance)
.maxCount(1).minCount(1).build();
```